# What is a good Java media library?

Tags: java, media, libraries

I want to be able to play video files that were downloaded from a web server, as .mkv files, in a Swing application. What is a good library for doing this? Also, although this isn't really necessary, I would prefer it if it was a jar file, so that it could download it via the application and the end user wouldn't have to install anything manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [vlcj - Java Framework for the vlc Media Player](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/)

Taken from the site:

> The vlcj project provides Java bindings to allow an instance of a native vlc media player to be embedded in a Java AWT Window or Swing JFrame. You get more than just simple bindings, you also get a higher level API that hides a lot of the complexities of working with libvlc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JMF: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html
or FMJ (open source version with some ffmpeg hooks): http://fmj-sf.net/
I'm not sure how well those projects are maintained though.